# How to let Vim work with pyenv?

Tags: vimscript-python, environment-variables, python

I've created some Python virtual environments:

```
hmanx ~ » pyenv virtualenvs
  3.7.4/envs/nn (created from /home/roach/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4)
  3.8.2/envs/py38 (created from /home/roach/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2)
  nn (created from /home/roach/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4)
  py38 (created from /home/roach/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2)
  vim-jupyter (created from /usr)
```

And I want to use the virtualenv `nn`, I have installed some packages, like `numpy`.

What I expected is command `:py3 import numpy` could work.

What I've tried:

1. use vim plugin: `Plug 'lambdalisue/vim-pyenv'`, but after run `PyenvActivate nn` command `:py3 import numpy` get error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`.
2. set `let &pythonthreehome='/home/roach/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/nn/bin/'`, get error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`
3. `export PYTHONPATH="/home/roach/.pyenv/versions/nn/bin":$PYTHONPATH`, then run vim get error same to method 1.

So, how to let vim use python in a virtual environment?

Or could use virtual python version when run

```
python3 << EOF

EOF
```

in a vim script.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the commands I use to create a python 3.6.0 pyenv on a Mac using homebrew.  Please note that I use neovim but the process to create a pyenv will not be much different for vim.

1. Install readline and xz along with pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv

   ```
   brew install pyenv pyenv-virtualenv readline xz
   ```
2. Install python 3.6.0

   ```
   CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
   LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
   pyenv install -v 3.6.0
   ```
3. Create the pyenv in your $HOME directory (~/.venv):

   ```
   ~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python3 -m venv ~/.venv
   ~/.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
   ~/.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install neovim pynvim
   ```
4. Set the g:python3_host_prog variable in your ~/.vimrc:

   ```
   let g:python3_host_prog=$HOME.'/.venv/bin/python3'
   ```
5. Check to make sure everything is correctly set up in neovim.

   ```
   :checkhealth
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for vim there is no `python3_host_prog` support.

Answer (score 0):

A method is decalare `export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS='--enable-shared'` before pyenv install a virtual env(thanks to [@puremourning](https://github.com/puremourning)):

`env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.8.2`, then activate it before open file use vim.

But still have a question, as my system python version is `3.8.3`, virtual version `3.8.2` works. But if I install a new virtual env `3.7.4`, failed.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue22213